# File download and cache

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, azure, blob

I have some xml files in the Azure blob storage. In a Web Unity App I need to download these files directly.
Like : http://myblobstorage.net/file.xml
Is there a way to disable cache because sometimes, the new file isn't used.
Is it possible to do that ? Maybe adding something in the request header ?
I saw another solution that consists to add a parameter at the end of the link, does it work ?
Like : http://myblobstorage.net/file.xml?nocache=randomnumber
Is it possible to save a file directly in the cache ? or in a temp folder ?
If you have any solution/suggestion !
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Like you said, you can disable the cache by adding something random to the query string (DateTim.Now.Ticks for example). An other way to control the cache is by setting the **CacheControl** property on your blob:

```
//Create a blob
CloudBlob blob = new CloudBlob("newcontainer/ablob.text", blobClient);
blob.UploadText("this is a blob");

//Set CacheControl property
blob.Properties.CacheControl = "public, max-age=31536000" // nocache is also an option;
blob.SetProperties();
```

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-properties-metadata/

Answer (score 0):

It's strange because when i add the cachecontrol property to no-cache, my xml file won't save. For now I will use the Tick at the end of the url.
Is it possible to save a file directly in the cache from asp.net ? or maybe access to the temp folder ?